# Empty dropdown when adding <select> using javascript with insertAdjacentHTML and ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-options

So here in this fiddle I did in both ways: https://jsfiddle.net/cicerohellmann/Lt8gju19/

In html I called it and it worked.

```
  <select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="item.friendName for item in options[1]"></select>
```

AM/PM: {{ampm}}

Appending using javascript doesn't work.

```
  html =
"<select ng-model='ampm' 
 ng-options='item.friendName for item in options[1]' 
 class='ng-pristine ng-valid'></select>";


 div = document.getElementById('test');
 div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

I'm using this data to test:

```
  $scope.options = [
    [{
      "friendName": "Escobar",
      "points": "200"
    }, {
      "friendName": "Pedro",
      "points": "200"
    }],
    [{
      "friendName": "Cicero",
      "points": "200"
    }, {
      "friendName": "Ciclano",
      "points": "200"
    }],
    [{
      "friendName": "Jeremias",
      "points": "200"
    }, {
      "friendName": "Boça",
      "points": "200"
    }],
    [{
      "friendName": "Leite com pera",
      "points": "200"
    }, {
      "friendName": "Rato borrachudo",
      "points": "200"
    }]
  ];
```

I tried for 2 days, researched about this case and nothing.
I don't get any errors too.

**And I really need this composition, because each dropdown will be created dynamically, that number over there will be setted dynamically too**

But of course, any better suggestion then the way im doing it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually updating this fiddle and I will post the complete and nice way to do this.
But, for now, this is my answer:

**Html5**

```
<div id="bob" ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="item.friendName for item in options[1]"></select>
  AM/PM: {{ampm}}
  <button ng-click="changeTopics()">Change</button>
  <button ng-click="click()"></button>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $compile) {
        var selectElement = angular.element("<select ng-model='ampm' ng-options='item.friendName for item in options[1]' class='ng-pristine ng-valid'></select>");

        var integer = 0;

        $scope.click = function(){

     selectElement = angular.element("<select ng-model=\"test"+ integer +"\"  ng-options=\"item.friendName for item in options[" + integer + "]\" class='ng-pristine ng-valid'></select>");

      htmlDiv = "<div id=\"test"+ integer +"\"></div>"

       var string ='test'+integer;

        console.log(integer);

    div = document.getElementById('bob');

    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlDiv);

    angular.element(document.getElementById('test'+integer)).append(selectElement);

    integer++;

    $compile(selectElement)($scope);
    }

    function removeElement(element) {
    element && element.parentNode && element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}


    $scope.changeTopics = function(){

        removeElement( document.getElementById("test"+ (integer-1)) );
    delete $scope.options.splice(integer,1);
        if(integer>0)
        integer--;
            console.log(integer);

    }
    $scope.ampm = 0;
    $scope.options = [
        [{
            "friendName": "Escobar",
            "points": "200"
        }, {
            "friendName": "Pedro",
            "points": "200"
        }],
        [{
            "friendName": "Cicero",
            "points": "200"
        }, {
            "friendName": "Ciclano",
            "points": "200"
        }],
        [{
            "friendName": "Jeremias",
            "points": "200"
        }, {
            "friendName": "Boça",
            "points": "200"
        }],
        [{
            "friendName": "Leite com pera",
            "points": "200"
        }, {
            "friendName": "Rato borrachudo",
            "points": "200"
        }]
    ];

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cicerohellmann/qavmoz22/4/)

I had help of a friend to discover the $compile. Thanks.